# Overwriting Text in a File When It's Already Open

Tags: php

I have a file that I'm opening for writing, like this:

```
if (!$idHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($fileName)";
        die();
    }
```

I then enter a loop where I'm incrementing a variable, `$beerId`, during each iteration. I want to save that variable to the file I have open, so I use the following code:

```
if (fwrite($idHandle, $beerId) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($fileName)";
    die();
    }
$beerId++;
```

However, this ends up creating a massive string of every beerId I encounter. What I want is to have the file populated ONLY with the last id I left off on.

I realize I could  put the write outside of the loop, but the script is volatile and likely to terminate prematurely with an error, so I want to have a reference to the last $beerId variable even in the event of an error that terminates the script before the loop is properly terminated.

Comment: use fclose to close the file according to the fopen documentation when you open a file with 'w' the content of the file is deleted, so open your file for each loop

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping to avoid having to open and close potentially 1000s of times within the loop. I realize the overhead is minimal for a small txt file, but I'm always on the hunt for a cleaner solution.

Comment: i think that a session would be a better approach than a file write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go back to the beginning of the file because `fwrite` keeps track of where it is in the file. Use [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php). Opening and closing the file several times in a loop is expensive and I don't see a reason to do that in this case. You should of course close the file when you're done with it.

You should add this just before you write to the file:

```
fseek($idHandle, 0);
```

That will move you to the beginning of the file, since your incrementing values you won't have to worry about removing the previous value.

**EDIT**
In my answer above i assume that the id's encountered are incremented values, but you don't say that so, if for example you encounter `id=10`, and then encounter `id=1`
the above would still result in `10` in the file, to handle that just add some padding to the string that you're writing using [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
str_pad($value_to_write, 10); //or whatever value is reasonable.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try memcache->increment().

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.increment.php

Use `$memcache->add('beer_id', 0);` to initialize it to zero. Then fetch `$beer_id` like `$memcache->get('beer_id')` for an initial sanity check, and then `$memcache->increment('beer_id');` for the next `$beer_id`.

Else, stick to `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php